# Apache Spark and Java error - Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 2

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am new in spark framework. I have tried to create a sample application using spark and java. I have the following code

Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Source

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;

public class SparkTest {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("Example Spark App")
                .setMaster("local[*]"); // Delete this line when submitting to a cluster
        JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        JavaRDD<String> stringJavaRDD = sparkContext.textFile("nationalparks.csv");
        System.out.println("Number of lines in file = " + stringJavaRDD.count());
    }
}
```

I am trying to run above code using IntelliJ IDE. But I got an error like this

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Users\amanaf\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=55665:C:\Users\amanaf\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\amanaf\IdeaProjects\testApp\target\classes;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-core_2.10\1.6.1\spark-core_2.10-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro-mapred\1.7.7\avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro-ipc\1.7.7\avro-ipc-1.7.7.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro\1.7.7\avro-1.7.7.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro-ipc\1.7.7\avro-ipc-1.7.7-tests.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.13\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.13\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\twitter\chill_2.10\0.5.0\chill_2.10-0.5.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\esotericsoftware\kryo\kryo\2.21\kryo-2.21.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\esotericsoftware\reflectasm\reflectasm\1.07\reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\esotericsoftware\minlog\minlog\1.2\minlog-1.2.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\1.2\objenesis-1.2.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\twitter\chill-java\0.5.0\chill-java-0.5.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\xbean\xbean-asm5-shaded\4.4\xbean-asm5-shaded-4.4.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-client\2.2.0\hadoop-client-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-common\2.2.0\hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.2\commons-cli-1.2.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-math\2.1\commons-math-2.1.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\xmlenc\xmlenc\0.52\xmlenc-0.52.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\commons-configuration\commons-configuration\1.6\commons-configuration-1.6.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\commons-digester\commons-digester\1.8\commons-digester-1.8.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.7.0\commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils-core\1.8.0\commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-auth\2.2.0\hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.4.1\commons-compress-1.4.1.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\tukaani\xz\1.0\xz-1.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-hdfs\2.2.0\hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\mortbay\jetty\jetty-util\6.1.26\jetty-util-6.1.26.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-app\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-common\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-client\2.2.0\hadoop-yarn-client-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\google\inject\guice\3.0\guice-3.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-test-framework\jersey-test-framework-grizzly2\1.9\jersey-test-framework-grizzly2-1.9.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-test-framework\jersey-test-framework-core\1.9\jersey-test-framework-core-1.9.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.0.1\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-client\1.9\jersey-client-1.9.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-grizzly2\1.9\jersey-grizzly2-1.9.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\grizzly\grizzly-http\2.1.2\grizzly-http-2.1.2.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\grizzly\grizzly-framework\2.1.2\grizzly-framework-2.1.2.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\gmbal\gmbal-api-only\3.0.0-b023\gmbal-api-only-3.0.0-b023.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\external\management-api\3.0.0-b012\management-api-3.0.0-b012.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\grizzly\grizzly-http-server\2.1.2\grizzly-http-server-2.1.2.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\grizzly\grizzly-rcm\2.1.2\grizzly-rcm-2.1.2.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\grizzly\grizzly-http-servlet\2.1.2\grizzly-http-servlet-2.1.2.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\javax.servlet\3.1\javax.servlet-3.1.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-json\1.9\jersey-json-1.9.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jettison\jettison\1.1\jettison-1.1.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\stax\stax-api\1.0.1\stax-api-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.3-1\jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.2.2\jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-jaxrs\1.8.3\jackson-jaxrs-1.8.3.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-xc\1.8.3\jackson-xc-1.8.3.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\contribs\jersey-guice\1.9\jersey-guice-1.9.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-server-common\2.2.0\hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-api\2.2.0\hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-core\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-common\2.2.0\hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-annotations\2.2.0\hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-launcher_2.10\1.6.1\spark-launcher_2.10-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-network-common_2.10\1.6.1\spark-network-common_2.10-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-network-shuffle_2.10\1.6.1\spark-network-shuffle_2.10-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\fusesource\leveldbjni\leveldbjni-all\1.8\leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.4.4\jackson-annotations-2.4.4.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-unsafe_2.10\1.6.1\spark-unsafe_2.10-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jets3t\jets3t\0.7.1\jets3t-0.7.1.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.3\commons-codec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\commons-httpclient\commons-httpclient\3.1\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\curator\curator-recipes\2.4.0\curator-recipes-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\curator\curator-framework\2.4.0\curator-framework-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\curator\curator-client\2.4.0\curator-client-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\zookeeper\zookeeper\3.4.5\zookeeper-3.4.5.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\jline\jline\0.9.94\jline-0.9.94.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\14.0.1\guava-14.0.1.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\orbit\javax.servlet\3.0.0.v201112011016\javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-math3\3.4.1\commons-math3-3.4.1.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.10\slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.10\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.10\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.7.10\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\ning\compress-lzf\1.0.3\compress-lzf-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\xerial\snappy\snappy-java\1.1.2\snappy-java-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\net\jpountz\lz4\lz4\1.3.0\lz4-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\roaringbitmap\RoaringBitmap\0.5.11\RoaringBitmap-0.5.11.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\commons-net\commons-net\2.2\commons-net-2.2.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\typesafe\akka\akka-remote_2.10\2.3.11\akka-remote_2.10-2.3.11.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\typesafe\akka\akka-actor_2.10\2.3.11\akka-actor_2.10-2.3.11.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\typesafe\config\1.2.1\config-1.2.1.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty\3.8.0.Final\netty-3.8.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\2.5.0\protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\uncommons\maths\uncommons-maths\1.2.2a\uncommons-maths-1.2.2a.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\typesafe\akka\akka-slf4j_2.10\2.3.11\akka-slf4j_2.10-2.3.11.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.10.5\scala-library-2.10.5.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\json4s\json4s-jackson_2.10\3.2.10\json4s-jackson_2.10-3.2.10.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\json4s\json4s-core_2.10\3.2.10\json4s-core_2.10-3.2.10.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\json4s\json4s-ast_2.10\3.2.10\json4s-ast_2.10-3.2.10.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scalap\2.10.0\scalap-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.10.0\scala-compiler-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-server\1.9\jersey-server-1.9.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\asm\asm\3.1\asm-3.1.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-core\1.9\jersey-core-1.9.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\mesos\mesos\0.21.1\mesos-0.21.1-shaded-protobuf.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-all\4.0.29.Final\netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\clearspring\analytics\stream\2.7.0\stream-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-core\3.1.2\metrics-core-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-jvm\3.1.2\metrics-jvm-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-json\3.1.2\metrics-json-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-graphite\3.1.2\metrics-graphite-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.4.4\jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.4.4\jackson-core-2.4.4.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-scala_2.10\2.4.4\jackson-module-scala_2.10-2.4.4.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-reflect\2.10.4\scala-reflect-2.10.4.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\com\thoughtworks\paranamer\paranamer\2.6\paranamer-2.6.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\apache\ivy\ivy\2.4.0\ivy-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\oro\oro\2.0.8\oro-2.0.8.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\tachyonproject\tachyon-client\0.8.2\tachyon-client-0.8.2.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\tachyonproject\tachyon-underfs-hdfs\0.8.2\tachyon-underfs-hdfs-0.8.2.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\tachyonproject\tachyon-underfs-s3\0.8.2\tachyon-underfs-s3-0.8.2.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\tachyonproject\tachyon-underfs-local\0.8.2\tachyon-underfs-local-0.8.2.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\net\razorvine\pyrolite\4.9\pyrolite-4.9.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\net\sf\py4j\py4j\0.9\py4j-0.9.jar;C:\Users\amanaf\.m2\repository\org\spark-project\spark\unused\1.0.0\unused-1.0.0.jar SparkTest
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
18/11/29 06:02:59 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.1
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/C:/Users/amanaf/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-auth/2.2.0/hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
18/11/29 06:02:59 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/11/29 06:02:59 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: amanaf
18/11/29 06:02:59 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: amanaf
18/11/29 06:02:59 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(amanaf); users with modify permissions: Set(amanaf)
18/11/29 06:03:00 INFO PlatformDependent: Your platform does not provide complete low-level API for accessing direct buffers reliably. Unless explicitly requested, heap buffer will always be preferred to avoid potential system unstability.
18/11/29 06:03:00 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 55702.
18/11/29 06:03:00 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
18/11/29 06:03:00 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
18/11/29 06:03:00 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@172.20.255.74:55715]
18/11/29 06:03:00 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 55715.
18/11/29 06:03:00 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
18/11/29 06:03:00 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
18/11/29 06:03:00 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at C:\Users\amanaf\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-183dfab1-dc04-401d-9b91-6caf7861709d
18/11/29 06:03:00 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 2.8 GB
18/11/29 06:03:00 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
18/11/29 06:03:00 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
18/11/29 06:03:00 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://172.20.255.74:4040
18/11/29 06:03:01 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
18/11/29 06:03:01 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 55752.
18/11/29 06:03:01 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 55752
18/11/29 06:03:01 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
18/11/29 06:03:01 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:55752 with 2.8 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 55752)
18/11/29 06:03:01 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
18/11/29 06:03:01 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 73.9 KB, free 73.9 KB)
18/11/29 06:03:01 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 9.8 KB, free 83.7 KB)
18/11/29 06:03:01 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on localhost:55752 (size: 9.8 KB, free: 2.8 GB)
18/11/29 06:03:01 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at SparkTest.java:12
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:362)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1015)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1015)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anonfun$getJobConf$6.apply(HadoopRDD.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anonfun$getJobConf$6.apply(HadoopRDD.scala:176)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getJobConf(HadoopRDD.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:46)
    at SparkTest.main(SparkTest.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 2
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3319)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1874)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:48)
    ... 23 more
18/11/29 06:03:01 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
18/11/29 06:03:01 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://172.20.255.74:4040
18/11/29 06:03:01 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
18/11/29 06:03:01 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
18/11/29 06:03:01 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
18/11/29 06:03:01 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
18/11/29 06:03:01 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
18/11/29 06:03:01 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
18/11/29 06:03:01 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
18/11/29 06:03:01 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\amanaf\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-38128353-d1ea-4f8e-9edb-62b97a6fa4b5
18/11/29 06:03:01 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Is anything I missed in the code?

Comment: I suppose you are using Java > 8, try with Java 8, this should work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The actual error in your log is :

> Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3,
>   length 2

This is because of the issue in `hadoop-common` library with Java 9 and above versions. For details of this error you can refer to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-14586.

This issue will be fixed in `Spark 3.0.0` release. Please refer to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26134. 
So for now you can downgrade your Java version to Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anything will work on Java 11; there's a truckload of things needing to be done; the stack trace of that one looks like someting minor about splitting jvm.version fields

See [HADOOP-15338](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-15338) for the TODO list for hadoop libs; I don't know of the spark or even scala library ones.

Options

1. Change the java version in the IDE
2. come and help fix all the java 11 issues. You are very welcome to join in there

Answer (score 0):

When you are using SPARK, you have to make sure you have all the right compatible software version. For e.g. Spark 2.4.0 compatible with Hadoop 2.7 or later. 
And from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/

> "Spark runs on Java 8+, Python 2.7+/3.4+ and R 3.1+. For the Scala
>   API, Spark 2.4.0 uses Scala 2.11. You will need to use a compatible
>   Scala version (2.11.x)."

Even though it says java 8+ its probably not probably tested.