# Why Spark needs Hadoop - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark, I am trying to run spark program but it is failing with Hadoop error, why Spark program needs Hadoop dependency?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Create_first_app_apacheSpark_part_1 {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    println("started")

    val sparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("Apache Spark")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    sparkSession.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    val list  = List("spark")
    val rdd = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(list, 1)
    //val value = rdd.map(e => e.toUpperCase())
    rdd.collect().foreach(println)

    sparkSession.stop()
    println("completed")
  }
}


started
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
23/07/15 23:16:36 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.4.4
23/07/15 23:16:37 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.parseStaticMapping(Groups.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:260)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:789)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:774)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:647)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1(Utils.scala:2422)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2422)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$5(SparkSession.scala:935)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
    at com.example.Create_first_app_apacheSpark_part_1$.main(Create_first_app_apacheSpark_part_1.scala:14)
    at com.example.Create_first_app_apacheSpark_part_1.main(Create_first_app_apacheSpark_part_1.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 2
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:4601)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2704)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:50)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: Issue resolved by thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53539160/2787184